# How to Detect A Value Change From Another Class

Tags: java, android, service

I am developing an app which includes a Spinner. I want it to: Detect an int change which depends on Spinner, if this value= is not 0, then it needs to create a String and instantiate it with the int value.

This is the Hider.class code:(Service)

```
public int NOTIF_ID =1;
public double timeup;
public static  String time;
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent argument, int flags, int startId)
{

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     NotificationManager notif_manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification.Builder notif_specs = new Notification.Builder(this);
    notif_specs.setContentTitle("Notification");
    notif_specs.setContentText("is now active..."+ timeup);
    notif_specs.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.combo);
    notif_specs.setTicker("Bildirim Geldi");
    notif_specs.setOngoing(true);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent bildirimin_niyeti = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NOTIF_ID, intent, 0);
    notif_specs.setContentIntent(bildirimin_niyeti);

    final Notification notif = notif_specs.getNotification();

    notif_manager.notify(NOTIF_ID, notif);



    if (MainActivity.timer_time!=0)
    {
        String str;
        switch (MainActivity.timer_time)
        {
            case 1: str = "Remaining 1m";
                            break;
            case 5: str = "Remaining 5m";
                            break;
            case 10: str = "Remaining 10m";
                            break;
        }

    }


    return START_STICKY; 
}

public void onDestroy()
{
    NotificationManager notif_mani = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notif_mani.cancel(NOTIF_ID);

    if(MainActivity.vib_bool)

    {
        final MediaPlayer oynatıcı = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.end);
        oynatıcı.start();
    }


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    super.onDestroy();

}


}
```

This code in not working cause OnStartCommand() is working once I guess. So how can I write this code to run repeatedly?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you need to know how to detect a value change from another class, or how to write code to run repeatedly?

Comment: Both of them. Actually second one is more important.

Comment: Then it's best to ask them as 2 separate questions and tailor each one to its specific information, otherwise people will get confused and the answers might not make sense

Comment: You are right, but at Hider.class there is if clause which looks at timer.time value. I think  this works for detecting a value. So if you help me at second problem I will be glad.